# Azure Mobile Service request URI is empty?

Tags: windows-phone-8, uri, azure-mobile-services

In what case can the Azure Mobile Service request URI be empty? I get this error occasionally and I don't know what causes it. Perhaps there's something wrong with my initialization. Basically I get an "Operation could not be completed. ()"

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: [zumo installation id]
  X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: [zumo app]
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.0
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.0.0.9903; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20324.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.0.0.9903; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20324.0)
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 105
}}
```

The client is initialized and query is sent like this:

```
mServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient(MobileServiceURI, MobileServiceApplicationKey);
mTable = OpenLogClient.GetTable<MyDatatype>();
await mTable.Insert(myCreatedOBject);
```

This works most of the time though, which is makes it weirder. Does it have something to do with timings? Do I have to wait for the service to be active? Is it possible that the client is initialized too early or called too early?

[Additional info] I have multiple clients to the same mobile service. Could this cause issues? Basically they're separately initialized in different threads. Basically I want to keep my code modular because these mobile services can (in the future) be different ones. For the sake of testing, however, I have one instance running and all my clients refer to the same client URI, application key combination.

Comment: In your code snippet did you mean OpenLogClient to be mServiceClient?  Client initialize isn't doing any network/etc type calls, so it is ready for use right away.  I do notice you are using an older version, may help to try upgrading to a newer copy (1.2.3 ideally) and confirm its not an old bug that was fixed.

Comment: Myeah, the name is wrong in the code, it should indeed be mServiceClient and not OpenLogClient. :) Anyway, upgrading is an option, but potentially costly one as the project quite extensively uses this and I've ran into some hardship previously. Anyway, I found this http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/03/azure-mobile-services-error-request.html that seems to be the same issue.